Volume Material Too Large to be visible in Small Object
I am having trouble controlling the outer fall off in a volume material...
i would like to control the falloff in this case so i have volume all the way to the edge of the object edges. Reason being because i need the volume to be inside a small object and it seems the falloff is such that nothing is visible.


What do you expect exactly ? This is how volume works, the less volume rays go through, the less visible is the volume. If you want an uniform color, you should go for a transparent shader (surface) instead. To say it differently, your question is equivalent to ask why an infinitely small sphere with a volume shader is invisible. No matter what you do, the outline of the object will always be transparent (even with a density of 10000).

wow gotta love these answers.
just because you dont know how to solve the problem dosnt mean people need a lesson on why.
let me rephrase.... does anybody (else) know how i can reduce the size of the volume so that i can use it in an "infinitely small" object?

I don't quite understand and I'm not giving any lesson. The border of the cube will always be transparent, no matter what you do it will be a gradient. Try a Transparent BSDF for example, if you want a uniform color. Maybe in addition to the volume shader ? As I said, volumes need depth that rays go through so that it is visible. The outline of an object is where rays go through an infinitely small volume, thus the falloff you are pointing out. I still don't fully understand what you want to achieve as a final result.

i want to reduce the size of that fall off, so that it can appear to be a smaller volume that can be visible in a smaller object. i mean if my simulating say steam in a small pipe for instance
